# I have problem when istalled sail on existing laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, docker-compose, docker-container, laravel-sail

I installed sail on existing project everything is okay but wen run `sail up -d`
the mysql image stopped after three or four second and this logs for the image

```
2023-10-23 11:36:45 [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.32-1.2.11-server
2023-10-23 11:36:45 [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.32-1.2.11-server
2023-10-23 11:36:45 2023-10-23T08:36:45.887725Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-10-23 11:36:45 2023-10-23T08:36:45.889533Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 1
2023-10-23 11:36:45 2023-10-23T08:36:45.895840Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-10-23 11:36:46 2023-10-23T08:36:46.017419Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-10-23 11:36:46 2023-10-23T08:36:46.114473Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-10-23 11:36:46 2023-10-23T08:36:46.114496Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-10-23 11:36:46 2023-10-23T08:36:46.114719Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010259] [Server] Another process with pid 62 is using unix socket file.
2023-10-23 11:36:46 2023-10-23T08:36:46.114731Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010268] [Server] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
2023-10-23 11:36:46 2023-10-23T08:36:46.114735Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-10-23 11:36:47 2023-10-23T08:36:47.674187Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

when run `docker ps -a` I get this and existed for the status

```
b7583851849c   sail-8.2/app             "start-container"        4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes               0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5173->5173/tcp, 8000/tcp   security-circles-laravel.test-1
cfddc513ce56   mysql/mysql-server:8.0   "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   4 minutes ago   Exited (1) 4 minutes ago
```

**Note**: I run the sail on the many projects all of these projects are work and everything okay

I want to solve it and run the mysql image via docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have another MySQL instance running.

Remove all containers with `docker compose down --volumes` and then start your containers again with `sail up -d`.